# My 2009 iMac keeps freezing up, only able to move the mouse cursor

Tags: imac, performance

I've been having problems with my iMac freezing up. My mouse pointer moves around the screen, but nothing else responds at all. My music keeps playing through iTunes. I've tried taking out all USB connected items and then trying to see if one of them was the culprit, but no luck. I have to physically switch the machine off and back on. It's only been doing it for a few weeks, nothing has been added, no new software downloaded ( apart from any Apple updates ). I have a 2009 iMac - 27" running Yosemite. I upgraded the RAM about 6 months ago, maybe longer but the problem never started occurring until a few weeks back.

Log output from around the time the freezing occurs:

```
6/4/15 11:49:25.008 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
6/4/15 11:49:51.426 AM locationd[80]: NETWORK: requery, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, items, fQueryRetries, 0, fLastRetryTimestamp, 455124469.5
6/4/15 11:49:51.508 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
6/4/15 11:49:52.211 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
6/4/15 11:49:54.028 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
6/4/15 11:52:53.175 AM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[1437]: Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
6/4/15 11:52:53.175 AM com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[1437]: Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
6/4/15 11:53:05.783 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
6/4/15 12:01:30.311 PM networkd[152]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.888 setting source application without entitlement
6/4/15 12:01:33.016 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
6/4/15 12:03:23.649 PM identityservicesd[290]: [Warning] ====== IDS Traffic Usage:
6/4/15 12:03:23.649 PM identityservicesd[290]: [Warning]    Service: com.apple.madrid
6/4/15 12:03:23.649 PM identityservicesd[290]: [Warning]      queries: 2
6/4/15 12:03:23.649 PM identityservicesd[290]: [Warning]      outgoing-messages: 4
6/4/15 12:03:23.649 PM identityservicesd[290]: [Warning]      incoming-messages: 5
6/4/15 12:03:23.649 PM identityservicesd[290]: [Warning] 
6/4/15 12:03:23.650 PM identityservicesd[290]: [Warning] ====== Done
6/4/15 12:07:08.000 PM kernel[0]: considerRebuildOfPrelinkedKernel prebuild rebuild has expired
6/4/15 12:07:08.000 PM kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): E00000000002 0x4e8 0x138d 0x0, 2
6/4/15 12:07:08.388 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: iTunes
6/4/15 12:07:08.388 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Finder
6/4/15 12:07:08.388 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Safari
6/4/15 12:07:08.388 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Microsoft Outlook
6/4/15 12:07:08.388 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Microsoft Word
6/4/15 12:07:08.389 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Microsoft Excel
6/4/15 12:07:08.389 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Messages
6/4/15 12:07:08.389 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: VueScan
6/4/15 12:07:08.389 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: i-Launcher is not running
6/4/15 12:07:08.389 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: RUNPATH=/Applications/Samsung/i-Launcher.app
6/4/15 12:07:09.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:09.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:09.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:09.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:09.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:10.964 PM fseventsd[43]: could not open <</Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid>> (No such file or directory)
6/4/15 12:07:10.964 PM fseventsd[43]: Failed to load UUID.  Removing all old log files in /Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd
6/4/15 12:07:10.965 PM fseventsd[43]: log dir: /Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd getting new uuid: 0C1FAE30-8280-4CC7-9167-BF17E244067A
6/4/15 12:07:11.297 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fc52b91b000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/i-Launcher
6/4/15 12:07:11.299 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fc52c250000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/NO NAME
6/4/15 12:07:11.611 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Error:577) vsd:0x7fc52c367000 Open failed.  failureCount:0 (null)
6/4/15 12:07:26.632 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Normal:166) vsd:0x7fc52c367000 DisabledStore recycle:0 context:{
    DisabledRecycleCount = 1;
}
6/4/15 12:07:26.680 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Error:577) vsd:0x7fc52c147000 Open failed.  failureCount:1 {
    DisabledRecycleCount = 1;
}
6/4/15 12:07:44.000 PM kernel[0]: disk3s1: media is not present.
6/4/15 12:07:44.000 PM kernel[0]: disk3s1: media is not present.
6/4/15 12:07:44.000 PM kernel[0]: disk3s1: media is not present.
6/4/15 12:07:44.000 PM kernel[0]: disk3s1: media is not present.
6/4/15 12:07:44.000 PM kernel[0]: msdosfs_fat_uninit_vol: error 6 from msdosfs_fat_cache_flush
6/4/15 12:07:49.000 PM kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): E00000000002 0x4e8 0x138d 0x0, 2
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: iTunes
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Finder
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Safari
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Microsoft Outlook
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Microsoft Word
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Microsoft Excel
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: Messages
6/4/15 12:07:49.512 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: VueScan
6/4/15 12:07:49.513 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: i-Launcher
6/4/15 12:07:49.513 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: i-Launcher is not running
6/4/15 12:07:49.513 PM iLauncherHelper[403]: RUNPATH=/Applications/Samsung/i-Launcher.app
6/4/15 12:07:50.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:50.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:50.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:50.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:50.000 PM kernel[0]: SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
6/4/15 12:07:50.664 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fc52b8c8800 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/i-Launcher
6/4/15 12:07:50.757 PM fseventsd[43]: disk logger: failed to open output file /Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd/00000000000f974c (No such file or directory). mount point /Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd
6/4/15 12:07:50.758 PM fseventsd[43]: disk logger: failed to open output file /Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd/00000000000f974c (No such file or directory). mount point /Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd
6/4/15 12:07:50.987 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fc52c135e00 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/NO NAME
6/4/15 12:07:51.033 PM fseventsd[43]: check_vol_last_mod_time:XXX failed to get mount time (25; &mount_time == 0x1048ff498)
6/4/15 12:07:51.033 PM fseventsd[43]: log dir: /Volumes/NO NAME/.fseventsd getting new uuid: 0C8D46CC-4C10-4CF5-89CB-1F8F0AD390E9
6/4/15 12:07:51.112 PM mds[57]: (Volume.Error:577) vsd:0x7fc52b91a000 Open failed.  failureCount:0 (null)
6/4/15 12:08:41.000 PM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1433434121 0
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.awdd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.cloudd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.clouddocs" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.commerce.asl" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.CoreDuetAdmissionControl" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.family.asl" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.ical" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.icloud.FindMyDevice" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.networking.symptoms" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.networking.symptoms" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.sandbox.telemetry" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.secinitd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM syslogd[39]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: vm_page_bootstrap: 3971444 free pages and 190092 wired pages
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: kext submap [0xffffff7f80a00000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff8000a00000]
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: zone leak detection enabled
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: multiq scheduler config: deep-drain 0, urgent first 1, depth limit 4, band limit 127, sanity check 0
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: standard background quantum is 2500 us
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: mig_table_max_displ = 13
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=0 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=1 Enabled
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for AMFI
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Apple Mobile File Integrity (AMFI)
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
6/4/15 12:09:19.000 PM kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
```

Comment: A nice "long" Console log would help us "see" what is going on. Open the Console app in your utility folder. Now find and copy some 50 lines around the time-stamp of the problem.

Comment: I've just added the log in my next post down.